# Access 2007: Insert query

Tags: ms-access, insert

I'm working on two tables in Access 2007 and the query below results in zero records.
I'd like to copy the client ID into the transactions table.

INSERT INTO Transactions (NAME_ID)
SELECT ID
FROM Clients
WHERE not exists (select * from Transactions
 where Transactions.Name=Clients.Name);

Thank you in advance,
Barry

Comment: No, it doesn't return any row from the query below:                                                             SELECT ID FROM Clients WHERE not exists (select * from Transactions where Transactions.Name=Clients.Name);

Comment: Clients table: 
ID, Name
23, John Smith 
24, Andrew Hills
25, Alma Life

Transactions table:
NAME_ID, Name
blank, John Smith
blank, John Smith
blank, Andrew Hills
blank, Alma Life
blank, Alma Life
blank, Alma Life

The problem is that I need to have a foreign key (NAME_ID) in the Transactions table in order to create the relationship with Clients table.

Comment: [SOLVED]: I created the query in Design View and it worked:

UPDATE Clients, Transactions SET Transactions.Client_ID = [Clients].[ID]
WHERE (([Clients].[Name]=[Transactions].[Name]));

Comment: This is my solution: UPDATE Clients, Transactions SET Transactions.Client_ID = [Clients].[ID] WHERE (([Clients].[Name]=[Transactions].[Name]));

Answer (score 1):

You need an UPDATE query, not a INSERT

```
UPDATE clients INNER JOIN transactions ON clients.Name = transactions.Name  
SET transactions.Name_ID = [clients].[ID];
```

The part after UPDATE defines the join between tables
the part after SET defines what items you want to update